# SwiftUI: Pop to root view when selected tab is tapped again

Tags: swift, swiftui

Starting point is a NavigationView within a TabView. I'm struggling with finding a SwiftUI solution to pop to the root view within the navigation stack when the selected tab is tapped again. In the pre-SwiftUI times, this was as simple as the following:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let navController = viewController as! UINavigationController
    navController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Do you know how the same thing can be achieved in SwiftUI?

Currently, I use the following workaround that relies on UIKit:

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIHostingController(rootView: MyCustomView() // -> this is a normal SwiftUI file
         .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)))
    navigationController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "My View 1", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
                
    // add more controllers that are part of tab bar controller
                
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [navigationController /* ,  additional controllers */ ]
    
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController // UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is possible approach. For `TabView` it gives the same behaviour as tapping to the another tab and back, so gives persistent look & feel.

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

[image: demo]

Full module code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestPopToRootInTab: View {
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State private var resetNavigationID = UUID()

    var body: some View {

        let selectable = Binding(        // << proxy binding to catch tab tap
            get: { self.selection },
            set: { self.selection = $0

                // set new ID to recreate NavigationView, so put it
                // in root state, same as is on change tab and back
                self.resetNavigationID = UUID()
        })

        return TabView(selection: selectable) {
            self.tab1()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                }.tag(0)
            self.tab2()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                }.tag(1)
        }
    }

    private func tab1() -> some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: TabChildView()) {
                Text("Tab1 - Initial")
            }
        }.id(self.resetNavigationID) // << making id modifiable
    }

    private func tab2() -> some View {
        Text("Tab2")
    }
}

struct TabChildView: View {
    var number = 1
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Child \(number)",
            destination: TabChildView(number: number + 1))
    }
}

struct TestPopToRootInTab_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestPopToRootInTab()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Asperi. However, this still doesn't give me the exact same behavior as we all know it from UIKit. Moreover, the TabBar does not preserve the navigation stack when switching between the tabs.

Comment: @burki I was also dissatisfied with the blown navigation stack on switching. I fixed with this slightly modified setter:

```
set: {
  let oldSelection = self.selection
  self.selection = $0
  // set new ID to recreate NavigationView, so put it
  // in root state, same as is on change tab and back
  if selection == oldSelection {
    self.settingsNavigationId = UUID()
  }
}
```

I would also love a nice pop animation, which would require passing a binding variable, but I really love how simple this solution is. It is restricted to a single file.

Comment: I made few improvements for real app:
1. @State private var navIds: [ UUID ] = [ UUID(), UUID(),UUID(), UUID(), UUID()]
2. let selectable = Binding(
      get: { self.tabSelection },
      set: { if tabSelection == $0 {
                self.navIds[$0] = UUID()
             }
             self.tabSelection = $0
           })
3. TabView (selection: selectable){
    Tab1(navId: navIds[0])
    Tab2(navId: navIds[1])
    ...
   }

Comment: add verification when setting "selectable" : if $0 == self.selection { self.resetNavigationID = UUID() }

Answer (score 10):

Here's an approach that uses a PassthroughSubject to notify the child view whenever the tab is re-selected, and a view modifier to allow you to attach .onReselect() to a view.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

enum TabSelection: String {
    case A, B, C // etc

}

private struct DidReselectTabKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: AnyPublisher<TabSelection, Never> = Just(.Mood).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

private struct CurrentTabSelection: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<TabSelection> = .constant(.Mood)
}

private extension EnvironmentValues {
    var tabSelection: Binding<TabSelection> {
        get {
            return self[CurrentTabSelection.self]
        }
        set {
            self[CurrentTabSelection.self] = newValue
        }
    }

    var didReselectTab: AnyPublisher<TabSelection, Never> {
        get {
            return self[DidReselectTabKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[DidReselectTabKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

private struct ReselectTabViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.didReselectTab) private var didReselectTab

    @State var isVisible = false
    
    let action: (() -> Void)?

    init(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.action = action
    }
        
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                self.isVisible = true
            }.onDisappear {
                self.isVisible = false
            }.onReceive(didReselectTab) { _ in
                if self.isVisible, let action = self.action {
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    public func onReselect(perform action: (() -> Void)? = nil) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(ReselectTabViewModifier(perform: action))
    }
}

struct NavigableTabViewItem<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.didReselectTab) var didReselectTab

    let tabSelection: TabSelection
    let imageName: String
    let content: Content
    
    init(tabSelection: TabSelection, imageName: String, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.tabSelection = tabSelection
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        let didReselectThisTab = didReselectTab.filter( { $0 == tabSelection }).eraseToAnyPublisher()

        NavigationView {
            self.content
                .navigationBarTitle(tabSelection.localizedStringKey, displayMode: .inline)
        }.tabItem {
            Image(systemName: imageName)
            Text(tabSelection.localizedStringKey)
        }
        .tag(tabSelection)
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .keyboardShortcut(tabSelection.keyboardShortcut)
        .environment(\.didReselectTab, didReselectThisTab)
    }
}

struct NavigableTabView<Content: View>: View {
    @State private var didReselectTab = PassthroughSubject<TabSelection, Never>()
    @State private var _selection: TabSelection = .Mood

    let content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        let selection = Binding(get: { self._selection },
                                set: {
                                    if self._selection == $0 {
                                        didReselectTab.send($0)
                                    }
                                    self._selection = $0
                                })

        TabView(selection: selection) {
            self.content
                .environment(\.tabSelection, selection)
                .environment(\.didReselectTab, didReselectTab.eraseToAnyPublisher())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far the best solution. Just a note, I had to remove the `self.isVisible` check in `ReselectTabViewModifier` before triggering `action()`. The `onAppear` & `onDisappear` doesn't trigger consistently.

Comment: Maybe I just can't get it, but I do not see where are you doing pop to root itself?

Answer (score 9):

Here's how I did it:

```
struct UIKitTabView: View {
    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<AnyView>]

    init(_ tabs: [Tab]) {
        self.viewControllers = tabs.map {
            let host = UIHostingController(rootView: $0.view)
            host.tabBarItem = $0.barItem
            return host
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabBarController(controllers: viewControllers).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

    struct Tab {
        var view: AnyView
        var barItem: UITabBarItem

        init<V: View>(view: V, barItem: UITabBarItem) {
            self.view = AnyView(view)
            self.barItem = barItem
        }
    }
}


struct TabBarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var controllers: [UIViewController]

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITabBarController {
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
        tabBarController.delegate = context.coordinator
        return tabBarController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UITabBarController, context: Context) { }
}

extension TabBarController {
    func makeCoordinator() -> TabBarController.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
        var parent: TabBarController
        init(_ parent: TabBarController){self.parent = parent}
        var previousController: UIViewController?
        private var shouldSelectIndex = -1
        
        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
            shouldSelectIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
            return true
        }

        func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
            if shouldSelectIndex == tabBarController.selectedIndex {
                if let navVC = tabBarController.viewControllers![shouldSelectIndex].nearestNavigationController {
                    if (!(navVC.popViewController(animated: true) != nil)) {
                        navVC.viewControllers.first!.scrollToTop()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    var nearestNavigationController: UINavigationController? {
        if let selfTypeCast = self as? UINavigationController {
            return selfTypeCast
        }
        if children.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        for child in self.children {
            return child.nearestNavigationController
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    func scrollToTop() {
        func scrollToTop(view: UIView?) {
            guard let view = view else { return }
            switch view {
            case let scrollView as UIScrollView:
                if scrollView.scrollsToTop == true {
                    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -scrollView.safeAreaInsets.top), animated: true)
                    return
                }
            default:
                break
            }

            for subView in view.subviews {
                scrollToTop(view: subView)
            }
        }
        scrollToTop(view: view)
    }
}
```

Then in ContentView.swift I use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            UIKitTabView([
                UIKitTabView.Tab(
                    view: FirstView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top),
                    barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Tab1", image: UIImage(systemName: "star"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"))
                ),
                UIKitTabView.Tab(
                    view: SecondView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top),
                    barItem: UITabBarItem(title: "Tab2", image: UIImage(systemName: "star"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"))
                ),
            ])
            
        }
    }
}
```

Note that when the user is already on the root view, it scrolls to top automatically

Comment: Looks like a great solution. However it says `nearestNavigationController` not found. What is it defined as?

Comment: @FilpeSa is there a way to change the height of the tabview controller in your `TabBarController: UIViewControllerRepresentable` ? I tried specifiying the height in `func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UITabBarController {` but it does nothing

Comment: @xiaolingxiao if there is a way I don't know how to do it. Try searching a little deeper, there must be a way somehow

Comment: That's a perfect solution for those who are stuck with the UIHosted TabViewController for some reason. Thank you! Btw, scroll to top works in a bit weird way. If your screen has a large navbar header style and it's on the default (initial) scroll position, tap to scroll will scroll it a bit down to hide the large navbar.

Comment: Also to pop to root I suppose to change `navVC.popViewController` to `navVC.popToRootViewController`

Answer (score 4):

## iOS 16 / `NavigationStack` approach with `PassthroughSubject`

Uses `willSet` on `selectedTab` to get the tap event, and uses a `PassthroughSubject` for sending the event to the children. This is picked up by the `.onReceived` and calls a function for popping the views from the `NavigationStack`

Did a full write up here: https://kentrobin.com/home/tap-tab-to-go-back/ and created a working demo project here: https://github.com/kentrh/demo-tap-tab-to-go-back

```swift
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab: Tab = .tab1 {
        willSet {
            if selectedTab == newValue {
                subject.send(newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    let subject = PassthroughSubject<Tab, Never>()

    enum Tab: Int {
        case tab1 = 0
    }
}
```

```swift
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: HomeViewModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $viewModel.selectedTab) {
            Tab1View(subject: viewModel.subject)
                .tag(HomeViewModel.Tab.tab1)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "1.lane")
                    Text("Tab 1", comment: "Tab bar title")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct Tab1View: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: Tab1ViewModel = .init()
    let subject: PassthroughSubject<HomeViewModel.Tab, Never>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.path) {
            List {
                NavigationLink(value: Tab1ViewModel.Route.viewOne("From tab 1")) {
                    Text("Go deeper to OneView")
                }
                NavigationLink(value: Tab1ViewModel.Route.viewTwo("From tab 1")) {
                    Text("Go deeper to TwoView")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Tab 1")
            .navigationDestination(for: Tab1ViewModel.Route.self, destination: { route in
                switch route {
                case let .viewOne(text):
                    Text(text)
                case let .viewTwo(text):
                    Text(text)
                }
            })
            .onReceive(subject) { tab in
                if case .tab1 = tab { viewModel.tabBarTapped() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
class Tab1ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [Route] = []

    func tabBarTapped() {
        if path.count > 0 {
            path.removeAll()
        }
    }
    enum Route: Hashable {
        case viewOne(String)
        case viewTwo(String)
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest solution in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did with introspect swiftUI library.
https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

```
struct TabBar: View {
    @State var tabSelected: Int = 0
    @State var navBarOne: UINavigationController?
    @State var navBarTwo: UINavigationController?
    @State var navBarThree: UINavigationController?

    
    var body: some View {
        
       return  TabView(selection: $tabSelected){
           NavView(navigationView: $navBarOne).tabItem {
               Label("Home1",systemImage: "bag.fill")
            }.tag(0)
            
           NavView(navigationView: $navBarTwo).tabItem {
                Label("Orders",systemImage: "scroll.fill" )
            }.tag(1)
            
           NavView(navigationView: $navBarThree).tabItem {
                Label("Wallet", systemImage: "dollarsign.square.fill" )
               // Image(systemName: tabSelected == 2 ? "dollarsign.square.fill" : "dollarsign.square")
            }.tag(2)
    
        }.onTapGesture(count: 2) {
            switch tabSelected{
            case 0:
                self.navBarOne?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            case 1:
                self.navBarTwo?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            case 2:
                self.navBarThree?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            default:
                print("tapped")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NavView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct NavView: View {
    
    @Binding var navigationView: UINavigationController?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail view")) {
                    Text("Go To detail")
                }
            }.introspectNavigationController { navController in
                navigationView = navController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This actually isn't the best approach because it makes the entire tab view and everything inside of it have the double-tap gesture which would pop the view to its root. My current fix for this allows for one tap to pop up root view haven't figured out how to add double tap

```
struct TabBar: View {
    @State var tabSelected: Int = 0
    @State var navBarOne: UINavigationController?
    @State var navBarTwo: UINavigationController?
    @State var navBarThree: UINavigationController?
    
    @State var selectedIndex:Int = 0
    var selectionBinding: Binding<Int> { Binding(
        get: {
            self.selectedIndex
        },
        set: {
            if $0 == self.selectedIndex {
                popToRootView(tabSelected: $0)
            }
            self.selectedIndex = $0
        }
    )}


    var body: some View {

       return  TabView(selection: $tabSelected){
           NavView(navigationView: $navBarOne).tabItem {
               Label("Home1",systemImage: "bag.fill")
            }.tag(0)

           NavView(navigationView: $navBarTwo).tabItem {
                Label("Orders",systemImage: "scroll.fill" )
            }.tag(1)

           NavView(navigationView: $navBarThree).tabItem {
                Label("Wallet", systemImage: "dollarsign.square.fill" )
               // Image(systemName: tabSelected == 2 ? "dollarsign.square.fill" : "dollarsign.square")
            }.tag(2)

        }
    }
    
    func popToRootView(tabSelected: Int){
        switch tabSelected{
        case 0:
            self.navBarOne?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        case 1:
            self.navBarTwo?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        case 2:
            self.navBarThree?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        default:
            print("tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually isn't the best approach because it makes the entire tab view and everything inside of it have the double-tap gesture which would pop the view to its root. Goona look into making it only on the tabBar item itself. I Will update answer when i find a solution

Comment: do you have any solution for this here?

Answer (score 0):

I took an approach similar to [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691250/1832831)
Use a combination of a custom binding, and a separately stored app state var for keeping state of the navigation link.

The custom binding allows you to see all taps basically even when the current tab is the one thats tapped, something that onChange of tab selection binding doesn't show.  This is what imitates the UIKit TabViewDelegate behavior.

This doesn't require a "double tap", if you just a single tap of the current, if you want double tap you'll need to implement your own tap/time tracking but shouldn't be too hard.

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var mainViewShowingDetailView = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var tabState: Int = 0
  @StateObject var appState = AppState()

  var body: some View {
    let binding = Binding<Int>(get: { tabState },
                   set: { newValue in 
      if newValue == tabState { // tapped same tab they're already on
        switch newValue {
        case 0: appState.mainViewShowingDetailView = false
        default: break
        }
      }
      tabState = newValue // make sure you actually set the storage
    })
    TabView(selection: binding) {
      MainView()  
        .tabItem({ Label("Home", systemImage: "list.dash") })
        .tag(0)
        .environmentObject(appState)
    }
  }
}

struct MainView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
  var body: {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("Hello World")
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(),
                       isActive: $appState.mainViewShowingDetailView,
                       label: { Text("Show Detail") })
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DetailView: View {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, “SwiftUI-friendly“ solution is to create a history of selected tabs and insert it into the environment. This way, you can observe this environment variable in *any* view of your app through `onChange`.

First, create a `Tab` model.

```
enum Tab: Int {
    static let `default`: Tab = .tabA
    
    case tabA
    case tabB
    case tabC
}
```

Secondly, create a new environment key named `tabs`.

```
private struct TabsEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: [Tab] = []
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var tabs: [Tab] {
        get { self[TabsEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[TabsEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

The last step is to create a `Binding<Tab>` returning the last selected tab, and updating the tab history each time a tab is tapped. Insert it into the environment with `.environment(\.tabs, tabs)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tabs: [Tab] = []
    
    var tab: Binding<Tab> {
        .init {
            tabs.last ?? .default
        } set: { newValue in
            tabs.append(newValue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: tab) {
            // …
        }
        .environment(\.tabs, tabs)
    }
}
```

From now on, any child view can access the `tabs` variable by calling `@Environment(\.tabs) private var tabs` and the latter can be observed using `onChange`.

```
struct TabAView: View {
    @Environment(\.tabs) private var tabs
    @State private var navigationPath = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            // …
        }
        .onChange(of: tabs, handleChange)
    }

    func handleChange(oldValue: [Tab], newValue: [Tab]) {
        guard let last = newValue.last else { return }
        guard let secondToLast = newValue.dropLast().last else { return }
        guard last == .tabA else { return }
        guard secondToLast == last else { return }
        if path.isEmpty {
            // do something else if you want
        } else {
            navigationPath.removeLast()
        }
    }
}
```