# SwiftUI TabView back to tab's root view by pressing the Tab Item

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When I go deeper in a view – by using navigationLinks –, I can't go back to the root view of the application by tapping on the TabItem, so if I tap on "ALL Cars" tab and click tap on "Home" again it will show the last state of that view.

How can I reset the view to show the initial state?

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
  HomeView()
  .tabItem {
    if(selectedTab == 0) {
      Image("home_active")
        .frame(height: 28)
    } else {
      Image("home_inactive")
        .frame(height: 28)
    }

    Text("HOME")
  }.tag(0)

  NavigationView {
    CarsView()
  }
  .navigationBarHidden(true)
  .tabItem {
    if(selectedTab == 1) {
      Image("cars_active")
    } else {
      Image("cars_inactive")
    }
    Text("ALL Cars").foregroundColor(.white)
  }.tag(1)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691250/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi it's a different problem

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?