# More TabView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

In SwiftUI I have a TabView that includes more than 6 tabs.  When I attempt to navigate to the More Tab, the More Tab will not work.  How would I make the more Tab work?  I can now navigate using all the other tabs but I can not navigate using the More Tab.

Thanks.

Here is the code that creates the TabView:

```
 struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selection = 0
@State private var resetNavigationID = UUID()

var body: some View {
    
    let selectable = Binding(
              get: { self.selection },
              set: { self.selection = $0
                self.resetNavigationID = UUID()
                

          })
    
    
    return TabView(selection: selectable) {
       
        self.SearchTabView().navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    Text("Search")
                }.tag(0)
            
 
        self.PostJobTabView().navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.rectangle")
                Text("Post a Job")
            }.tag(1)
        
        
        self.JobHistoryTabView().navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.3")
                Text("My Jobs History")
            }.tag(2)
        
    
    self.SignInTabView().navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "lock.icloud")
            Text("Sign In")
        }.tag(3)
               
}



private func SearchTabView() -> some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            SearchView().navigationBarTitle("Search", displayMode: .inline)
        }

    }.id(resetNavigationID)
    
   }


private func PostJobTabView() -> some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            PostJobView().navigationBarTitle("Post a job", displayMode: .inline)
        }
       }
   }

private func JobHistoryTabView() -> some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            MyJobsHistoryView().navigationBarTitle("My Jobs History", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}


private func SignInTabView() -> some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            SignInView().navigationBarTitle("Sign In", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691250/12299030?